# MySQL Like statement in SELECT column_name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select the column names from a specific table, where the table name is like '98673'

So I am using this:

```
SELECT 
    column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name='lime_survey_98673'
    AND column_name LIKE '98673'
```

However this will not result in any data.
Though I do have column names with '98673Blah' in there.

I know I must be doing something wrong, but what??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the LIKE you have to add a wildcard %, so:

```
SELECT 
    column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name='lime_survey_98673'
    AND column_name LIKE '98673%'
```

Comment: Great I was overlooking that indeed!

Answer (score 4):

USE `%`

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='lime_survey_98673'
AND column_name LIKE '%98673%'
```

`%` indicates a wildcard and returns any `column_name` that contains `98673`

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the part `AND column_name LIKE '98673'` unless you really need it or:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name LIKE '%lime_survey_98673%'
-- AND column_name LIKE '%98673%'  // only if needed
```

For more information take a look at the documentation for:

- [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
- [STRCMP() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `%`

```
SELECT 
    column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name='lime_survey_98673'
    AND column_name LIKE '%98673%'
```

this means that `column_name` contains `98673`.

Answer (score 1):

**One can do it this way too :**

```
show columns from lime_survey_98673 like '%98673%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add wildcard with table name also.

```
SELECT 
    column_name,
    table_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    schema_name = 'db_name' 
    AND table_name='%98673%'
    AND column_name LIKE '%98673%'
```

In this way you can get columns name list all tables and there columns name contain the text like '98673' from specific database or schema.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name` LIKE 'coloums_name';
```